# Merge two arrays of objects and get the unique objects PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here i need some help about merging of two arrays.

This is the sample code i have

```
    $tasks = array();
    $task_user = new Task_User;
    $task_user->setUserId($this->session_data['userId']);
    $user_taskIds = $this->getUserTasks($task_user);
    foreach ($user_taskIds as $row) {
        $task = new Task;
        // $task->setBranchId($branch_id);
        $task->setTaskId($row->getTaskId());
        $tasks[] = $this->getTask($task);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($tasks);
    $pageData['userTasks'] = $tasks;
    $task = new Task;
    // $task->setBranchId($branch_id);
    $task->setCreated($this->session_data['userId']);
    $tasks1 = $this->getBranchTasks($task);
    if (!empty($tasks1[0]))
    {
        $pageData['userTasks'] = $tasks1;
    }
    print_r($tasks1);
    print_r($pageData['userTasks']);
```

$this->load->view('home', $pageData);

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Task Object
        (
            [task_id:Task:private] => 22
            [service_id:Task:private] => 1
            [branch_id:Task:private] => 1
            [customer_id:Task:private] => 121
            [lead_id:Task:private] => 0
            [name:Task:private] => YTY0000022
        )

    [1] => Task Object
        (
            [task_id:Task:private] => 24
            [service_id:Task:private] => 1
            [branch_id:Task:private] => 1
            [customer_id:Task:private] => 1046
            [lead_id:Task:private] => 0
            [name:Task:private] => YTY0000024
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Task Object
        (
            [task_id:Task:private] => 9
            [service_id:Task:private] => 1
            [branch_id:Task:private] => 1
            [customer_id:Task:private] => 599
            [lead_id:Task:private] => 0
            [name:Task:private] => YTY0000009
        )

    [1] => Task Object
        (
            [task_id:Task:private] => 10
            [service_id:Task:private] => 1
            [branch_id:Task:private] => 1
            [customer_id:Task:private] => 313
            [lead_id:Task:private] => 0
            [name:Task:private] => YTY0000010
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Task Object
        (
            [task_id:Task:private] => 9
            [service_id:Task:private] => 1
            [branch_id:Task:private] => 1
            [customer_id:Task:private] => 599
            [lead_id:Task:private] => 0
            [name:Task:private] => YTY0000009
        )

    [1] => Task Object
        (
            [task_id:Task:private] => 10
            [service_id:Task:private] => 1
            [branch_id:Task:private] => 1
            [customer_id:Task:private] => 313
            [lead_id:Task:private] => 0
            [name:Task:private] => YTY0000010
        )

)
```

So, finally i need the two arrays of objects should be combined with unique objects and pass it to one array. I tried it from last 6 hours. But i am unable to get it. Please help me out
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you amend the task classes?  If so arrange for it to tell you the id. Another way to get at the private data is to `serialize` the task and dig it out of the string?

Comment: If they are the same objects then [spl_object_hash — Return hash id for given object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) maybe useful?

Answer (score 0):

In a few short tests, it appears than in_array works with objects. it would not be able observe private variables however, without unmasking them, which is an exercise i leave to you.

```
$tasks2 = [];
foreach($tasks as $t){
    if(!in_array($t,$tasks2){
        array_push($tasks2,$t);
    }
}
```

Comment: If You see the code , i pushed the $tasks and $tasks1  into single array..Then it is overriding

Comment: No you didn't. You replaced the array entirely `$pageData['userTasks'] = $tasks1;`

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line 
    ...

```
if (!empty($tasks1[0]))
{
    $pageData['userTasks'] = $tasks1;
}
...
```

into 
    ...

```
if (!empty($tasks1[0]))
{
    $pageData['userTasks'] = array_replace($pageData['userTasks'], $tasks1);
}
...
```

Comment: what happens if i use this one